# Doing math on a piped property powershell

Tags: powershell, math

Very new to doing math on properties...
I'm trying :

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -computer $poste | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name  GB -Value {[int]($_.size/1GB)} -PassThru |  select model, size,GB
```

and I think i'm referecing the SIZE property wrong because I get :

```
model                                            size GB
-----                                            ---- --
Corsair Neutron XTI SSD SCSI Disk Device 480101368320  0
ST350041 3AS SCSI Disk Device            500105249280  0
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as an explicit ForEach-Object:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive  | %{Add-Member -Input $_ -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name  GB -Value {[int]($_.size/1GB)} -PassThru} |  select model, size,GB
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression is a bit simpler:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive | select model, size,@{n="GB";e={[int]($_.size/1GB)}}
```

And it works as well.

Comment: And, since CIM is the future; `Get-CimInstance CIM_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property model, size,@{n="GB";e={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Expression` in your select statement to calculate size in GB.

**Ex:**

```
Get-WMIObject win32_diskdrive -computer $poste  | Select  @{Label = "Model";Expression = {$_.Model}},
        @{Label = "Size";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f($_.Size) }},
        @{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size / 1gb)}} #This will devide size by 1gb
```

Comment: Good way as well, however i'm confused, what is 0:N1 and  -f ?

Comment: As you aren't changing the properties of Model/Size, you can just select them as normal: `Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $poste | Select Model,Size,@{Label = "GB";Expression = {[int]($_.Size / 1gb)}}`

Comment: -f is the [String Format Operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). 0:N1 is a format descriptor.

Comment: `"{0:N1}" -f` is being used to limit the number of decimal places, eg change `465.759308338165` to `466`. It is used here as the result isn't being cast to an `[int]` (which achieves the same result).

Comment: @JamesC. It is not exactly the same thing. {0:N1} will have 1 decimal point displayed. Casting it to [int] would not.

Comment: @EBGreen Yes, I'd misread as `0:N0` (which would have been OP intention looking at their code)